# Is there a Best Practice for multiple Http Post - RPC style, custom MediaTypeFormatter or Other

Tags: asp.net-web-api, webapi, asp.net-web-api-routing

I'm not looking to start a holy war but looking for maybe a document on best
practices for creating APIs which contain multiple HTTP verbs.

I inherited a 4.7.2 Web API project and trying to straighten out some things and
hopefully sometime in the future get to move it to .NET Core.

In the mean time I have a resource that will be gaining new functionality.
To keep this simple, let's just say it is a "document".

Currently there is a [HttpPost] that is used to create the document metadata.
The ask is to extend it to provide "Clone", "Split", "Merge" all of which are
creation types but all have a dependency on an existing document.

I can go the RPC style

- api/document/{action}/{id}
- api/document/{id}/{action}

which flies in the face of HTTP REST implementations.
The second implementation is a little better but that "action" is not really a "resource".

The other option I have is to have a single HttpPost that looks like the code at the bottom
and pass a custom content-type.  If I go this route, I must implement a MediaTypeFormatter
or I get a exception generated.  I currently have this implemented and working, it's just
going to be a maintenance nightmare when/if I start adding/changing to use this methodology.

As I said, I'm on 4.7.2 so ConsumesAttribute is not available to me.

The question I have is....   **Is there a best practice????**

Thoughts?

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] string metadata)
{
   var ct = Request.Headers["Content-Type"]
   switch (ct)
   {
    // Call operation that will handle that Content Type which 
    // will deserialize document into a specific object type
   }
}

  Action  Content Type
  Create  application/json
  Clone   application/vnd.mycompany.create-from-existing.v1+json
  Split   application/vnd.mycompany.split-from-existing.v1+json
  Merge   application/vnd.mycompany.merge-existing.v1+json

public class MyContentTypeToStringFormatter : MediaTypeFormatter { }
```

Comment: I would try to use HTTP verbs to map when possible e.g. `PUT` == `Merge`, after that I would come up with naming convention as you mentioned `api/document/{id}/clone/{newid}` or `api/document/{id}/split/{newid}`